# How to enlarge root and home on dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted

I want to shrink my windows c: partition with 200 gb and use this to enlarge my linux partition. This is the situation at this moment:

[image: partition table]

So this is my plan:

sda2 (win c): -200gb 
sda5 (root): +25 gb 
sda7 (home): +175 gb

As i read, I should do this from live cd so that partitions are not mounted. Shrinking sda2 is fairly straightforward, but. Then I will have unallocated space from 200gb after sda2, but how can i distribute this to sda5 & sda7 (mind you: sda 6 swap) is in the middle of them.

Anyone has experience with this and can help me?

Also, afterwards i will have to rebuild grub i think by executing:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Or not?

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but want to be sure before executing this thorough operation.

Thanks!

Comment: From the live system, you just have to `swapoff` (right click), then enlarge the extended partition, then move the internal partitions to the left and enlarge them. Please note: BACKUP everything before doing it. Moreover, the precess of moving to the left might take some times (hours, even days), so be sure that you have enough time (and your computer should always have power).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Shrink sda2.
2. Enlarge sda3 so that no unallocated space is left.
3. Enlarge sda5 to the beginning of sda3 then shrink it to the desired
   size by dragging from the right end of sda5 to the left.
4. Repeat step 3 for sda6 & sda7.

Ah, don't forget to turn off swap, which will be mounted by the live system.

Comment: Turning off swap is done by this code?

sudo swapoff -a

Comment: "swapoff -a" will turn off all swap partitions. You can as well do "swapoff /dev/sda6" or right klick the partition in gparted and deactivate it.

Comment: I succeeded in doing in the way you outlined. I did receive some warnings is gparted (cannot remember them, made a screenshot but apparantly didn't save though). "file check error on /sdaX trying to repair". Some had a red cross (in my swap partition) and some a green V (on my home folder)

Comment: Nevertheless, great program Gparted with lots of power and easy to use. For further reference: it also gave a warning that i probably would not be able to boot as i resized a system partition. Upon restarting Ubuntu stared without problem. Before resizing, i defragmented my windows c: partition (sda2)